# Is there a public dataset with the complete i18n list of Countries, states, languages, area codes, cities, postal codes and Timezones?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, internationalization, yahoo-api, master-data-services

I am developing an generic application for the global audience and would like to capture this Master Data so that appropriate UI components can be developed to support features such as Autocomplete and dependent picklists.

The master data I am looking for is:

```
Country
--> ISO Country Codes, Telephone Codes, IP Address Ranges, Timezone Info, Capital Cities
--> State/Regions/Provinces
-----> State Codes, Telephone Area Codes, IP Address Ranges, Timezone Info, Capital Cities
-----> Districts/Counties
-----> Timezone Info (Constant Timezones Counties in USA such as in Indiana)
--------> Cities
------------> Postal Codes, IP Address Ranges
```

I have checked the GeoNames but the data does not seem to cover all information.
I have also checked the Facebook API but there was no complete download. 
I have also checked the sources mentioned in other questions such as opensourcegis, osgeo and freegis

I could find some commercial packages such as GeoDataSource but I would rather have a public dataset with Apache / CreativeCommons license.

I could find references  Yahoo! Geo PlaceFinder etc web services but would like to have the data as Spreadsheet, Tab delimited file, XML or may be a database dump, that would be great. It’s even better if there is a means to capture the incremental updates of this public dataset.

If none is available, I might just have to develop a simple crowd sourcing app tailor made to this requirement.